# suppress dialog warnings in MS Word on file open

Tags: html, vba, ms-word, automation

I am using OLE Automation in VBA to open several hundred htm files and save them as word doc files.

Occasionally this dialog shows up:

```
Linked style sheets are only supported in web format files.  By saving to this format, all links to style sheets will be lost.
```

I have Application.displayalerts set to false - is there any way to ignore that particular dialog and carry on execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel accepts Application.DisplayAlerts = none, Word uses three Long constants: wdAlertsNone, wdAlertsAll and wdAlertsMessageBox. If you use wdAlertsNone, your code should work ;)

Comment: no luck, but thanks anyway, may just have to live with it as the only alternative is subclassing the dialog and sending a click event to the continue button's window!!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line before calling `SaveAs()`:

```vb
Application.ActiveDocument.OptimizeForWord97 = True
```